# Proper Switch Statement?

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="text/javascript">
var URL = document.URL;
<--switch (URL) {
   case "http://www.greatarchitect.us/defatank":
      document.write("Displaying Defatank");
      break;
   case "seeingblue":
      document.write("Displaying SeeingBlue");
      break;
   case "shiroshii":
      document.write("");
      break;
   case "theend66":
      document.write("");
      break;
   case "wakawaka647":
      document.write("");
      break;
   case "xtheguythatplays":
      document.write("");
      break;
}-->
</script>
```

What is wrong with the above code? I'm trying to load specific data based on the page URL.

I updated the code. How would I simply display the URL to be sure I'm checking my case against the right url?

Comment: _"What is wrong with the above code?"_...I don't know. I was about to ask you the same question. Does something not work? Do you get an error? My crystal ball is on vacation this week...

Comment: your first line is incorrect. `<script type="text/javascript">` is what you want

Comment: document.url gets the full URL. What errors are you getting? Have you  tried logging URL to see what it is?

Comment: First of all, you have to tell what you are expecting to achieve with the code you posted. Second, document.url is not what you are expecting. Do some google first.

Comment: Won't it be tricky to keep adding cases? You might have more success looping over an array. And "document.URL" works, "document.url" will return undefined. (at least for me, idk if chrome is special in some way.)

Comment: @zz3599 - true, but most browsers will still deal with the code.

Comment: I made the suggested corrections. Still no luck. What would I write to simply display the URL so I know what I should be checking my case against?

Comment: Ok, I made progress, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.URL` returns the entire web address. you need to filter/chop it down in order to only manipulate the part you want.

also you're declaring your script wrong. it should be `<script type="text/javascript">`.

:)

Comment: document.URL (URL all caps)

Comment: URLs are so viariable, maybe you need some work before the switch and also add a default statement.